# Paginator vs NextToken in AWS API calls

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, paginator

I have been using both paginator and nextToken while making AWS api call using python boto3, But Is there really any difference in **cost/number of api calls** behind them?
Note : Apart from code complexity

I know there can be some difference when the result we are looking for is available in the first page itself. But In my case, I am checking on getting all the 10,000+ pages...

Answer (score 0):

> But Is there really any difference in cost/number of api calls behind them?

Boto3 paginators are just a wrapper that calls NextToken for you. So no, there is no difference in cost or number of actual API calls when using either method.